# Google Drive API with Requests.

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api

I would like to pipe a remote file stream to google drive. Using the [request lib](https://github.com/mikeal/request) you can do something like to download things locally.

```
request('http://google.com/doodle.png').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('doodle.png'))
```

I would like to somehow pipe that stream to google drive using the [google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client). Based on the examples it would be something like:

```
  // insertion example
  client
      .drive.files.insert({ title: 'Test', mimeType: 'text/plain' })
      .withMedia('text/plain', 'Hello World')
      .withAuthClient(auth)
      .execute(function(err, result) {
    console.log('error:', err, 'inserted:', result.id);
  });
```

I'm not sure how or where to pair the write stream to the withMedia.

Answer (score 0):

```
client
      .drive.files.insert({ title: 'Test', mimeType: 'text/plain' })
      .withMedia('image/jpeg', fs.createReadStream('doodle.png'))
      .withAuthClient(auth)
      .execute(function(err, result) {
    console.log('error:', err, 'inserted:', result.id);
  });
```